# Haskell Build Automation

Tags: haskell, continuous-integration, build-automation

What is the preferred way to automate build/test/ci/doc-gen/... for a Haskell project?

At the moment I use Cabal for the "final" build and bash-scripts to automate testing/checkins/doc-gen/.. but I would like to replace the bash-scripts.

I've installed Nemesis (rake for Haskell according to the author) but I'm not yet sure it's the right tool.

Just to clarify: I'm looking for something that I can add custom commands with custom arguments to (is it possible with Cabal?), i.e.

> foo test unit
>
> foo test db
>
> foo test all
>
> foo db migrate
>
> ...

Answer (score 7):

Cabal is the preferred way to build/test/generate docs for Haskell projects. ~1500 projects are built this way on hackage:

To build docs for your project:

- cabal haddock

To build your project:

- cabal install

To clean your   project:

- cabal clean

Comment: It sounded like he was looking for something that ran cabal for him (at least, thats what I got from the continuous-integration tag).

Comment: I'm using `cabal build` seems to be a fair bit faster. You don't need to install every time.

Answer (score 6):

I might be old fashioned, but I just set up my `.cabal` file and darcs repository and add a `Makefile` that with the dependencies of its default action tries to build my package, runs any tests, checks in the current build, and fires off `cabal haddock` to generate my documentation.

Then I just crack open `vim` and keep call out to `make` as needed.